# I'm not able to execute "relog" through c# code, but I'm able to execute through cmd.exe

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've come across a strange scenario where I'm able to execute a relog command
(relog C:\PerfLogs\Admin\D-113067088_* -f SQL -o SQL:relog!D-113067088) through command prompt succesfully but when I try to execute the same command via my c# code it throws an error.

The error I get is "Call to SQLAllocConnect failed with [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application."

the argument which I pass for my c# code below is /c relog C:\PerfLogs\Admin\test_000001.blg -f SQL -o SQL:relog!D-113067088

```
            Process Proc = new Process();
            Proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
            Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            Proc.Start();
            Proc.WaitForExit();
            string errorMessage = Proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            string outputMessage = Proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            int exitCode = Proc.ExitCode;
            Proc.Close();
            return exitCode;
```

Comment: Do you use the word "not" correctly in the title? It seems perhaps the second not shouldn't be there?

Comment: rather than cmd.exe, what happens if you call the relog program directly?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thanks for bringing it in to notice. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a 64-bit OS, 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC drivers are separate, and which is used depends on the application architecture.  You can use the 64-bit DSN if you build your app to target X64.  Alternatively, you can create a 32-bit ODBC DSN using the C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe utility.

Comment: If he's starting an external program, does the architecture of the program that started it have anything to say? Meaning, if you start process A which is 32-bit, and A starts process B which is AnyCPU, will B start as 32-bit as well or could it start as 64-bit on a 64-bit CPU? Since he's able to run the program manually, it seems the relog program is correctly written.

Comment: Yes, the architecture of the invoking program is significant.  There are 32 and 64 bit versions of the relog utility, and the one invoked depends on the architecture of the invoking app.  The ODBC driver must match the architecture too.

Comment: Wonderful. Worked. Thank you so much.